# Hiding the cursor in Windows CE

Tags: c#, windows-ce, cursor

I have a fullscreen application running on Windows CE 6.0 which will only be manipulated using the finger or a stylus.

So I don't need the mouse cursor, which I'm hiding using `Cursor.Hide()`.
However, when I use the stylus to manipulate something on the screen, the mouse cursor is printed while the stylus touch the screen.

Is there a way to **make the cursor not show when touching the screen?**

BTW: the application will be the only thing running, so system-wide solution are possible, but I'd rather keep it inside the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a system-wide solution, in case you can create the OS, you can remove the mouse cursor component from the catalog (`SYSGEN_CURSOR`).

---

For a local solution here is a suggestion (never tried it):
You can replace the icon with a blank icon so you won't see any cursor while inside your form. Once you leave the borders of your form you can restore the usual icon.

Read [How to use custom cursors](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors). I checked that the [`Cursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor%28VS.80%29.aspx) class is available with the CF. There are two other functions needed to be P/Invoked that are available under CE:

- [`GetIconInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504094.aspx)
- [`CreateIconIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908175.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, the `Cursor` class of the compact framework is really limited. I can't instantiate it and it only accepts `Cursors.Default` and `Cursors.Wait`. I'll look into `SYSGEN_CURSOR` but I'm not in charge of building the OS.

Comment: Another suggestion I haven't tried: for a system wide solution - you can try to replace the mouse pointer icon on the storage and I guess Windows will use that. If it works, you might need to overwrite it after every boot since it might be RAM based storage.

Comment: I assume `Cursor.Hide()` is the same, but did you try `ShowCursor`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee506127.aspx